# Feasibility of Pyrolytic Rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I've been asked whether or not the above reaction happens - and if it does, what's the mechanism? 
I'm really confused, I think it shouldn't happen; but I'd like to confirm with Chem SE, just to be sure.

If it doesn't happen, then what are the possible methods of accomplishing the conversion?

Comment: Seems unlikely as it would involve acetate anion attacking the phenyl ring. Think it more likely you would get benzonitrile and acetic acid

Comment: Maybe oxime/methylketone might form in similar rearrangement.

Comment: How is this off topic? It's not a homework question, and I have no other way of finding out whether or not the reaction is feasible.

Comment: If you describe *why* you think it's unlikely to happen there's a good chance it will be reopened.